# is EnQlave by QRL for post quantum Etheerum dependent on QRL Blockchain?

Tags: wallets, security, post-quantum

EnQlave is an initiative by QRL to secure Ethereum blockchain against quantum attacks. What QRL people claim is that the EnQlave wallet will not be dependent on any other blockchain other than Ethereum [ [Here](https://www.reddit.com/r/QRL/comments/iz3zep/qrl_long_run/) ]. But to create a wallet in EnQlave we need the XMSS public key whose generation has to be done through the QRL wallet only as of now.

These are assumptions I made as there is no documentation available.

- When a user wants to convert his Etherium to Post Quantum Etherium he has to make ac. in QRL, convert his Etherium to Quanta, and transfer it to EnQlave Wallet.
- Conversion of Quanta to EnQRT(or wQRT) is one-to-one. Will the EnQRT price be in sync with Quanta? If so, that means explicit dependency on QRL Blockchain.

I want to clarify whether my assumptions are True/ Flase and also whether Enqlave depends on the QRL blockchain or not.

Comment: The project seems to be independent of the Ethereum project. It looks like another buzzword project.

Comment: @Ismael It looks promising even though it will not secure the entire blockchain. It may be the temporary solution If any breakthrough happens in quantum computers immediately. But there is no complete documentation for this project available which is the problem.